# How to define multiple controls in the same column of a WPF Gridview?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, gridview, data-binding

I had a question in regards to how to set different data types in the same column of a WPF GridView? Basically, I want to have a column where the first row will have a checkbox, 2nd row will have a combobox and the 3rd row will have a textblock. I want to use this type of 25 columns in a GridView.

[Sample image Of how do I want the GridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJxDf.png)

I had tried doing this by using a common DataTemplate and to bind it in each GridViewColumn. But I don't know it's possible or not to pass the exact object to a DataTemplate.

Here is my Code in MainWIndow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TestProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestProject"
    xmlns:enums="clr-namespace:TestProject.Enums"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomGridCell">
        <StackPanel>
            <CheckBox Name="CheckControl" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <CheckBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ControlType}" Value="{x:Static enums:ControlType.Boolean}">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding BoolProp}"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </CheckBox.Style>
            </CheckBox>

            <ComboBox Name="ComboControl" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboMethod}">
                <ComboBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ControlType}" Value="{x:Static enums:ControlType.ComboBox}">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                <Setter Property="SelectedValue" Value="{Binding ComboProp}"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ComboBox.Style>
            </ComboBox>

            <TextBlock Name="TextControl">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ControlType}" Value="{x:Static enums:ControlType.TextBlock}">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding NormalProp}"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

<Grid>
    <ListView Margin="10" Name="lvUsers">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Mail" Width="150">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mail}" TextDecorations="Underline" Foreground="Blue" Cursor="Hand" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Custom 1"  Width="50" CellTemplate="{StaticResource CustomGridCell}"/>

                <GridViewColumn Header="Custom 1"  Width="50" CellTemplate="{StaticResource CustomGridCell}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Here is the code of MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
    public MainWindow ()
        {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<User> items = new List<User>();

        items.Add(new User()
            {
            Name = "John Doe",
            Age = 42,
            Mail = "john@doe-family.com",
            Custom1= new MyObject {
                ControlType = ControlType.Boolean,
                BoolProp = true,
                ComboProp = "Item 1",
                NormalProp = 1.2,
                ComboMethod = new ObservableCollection<string>(FillComboBox())
                },
            Custom2 = new MyObject
                {
                ControlType = ControlType.Boolean,
                BoolProp = true,
                ComboProp = "Item 2",
                NormalProp = 2.2,
                ComboMethod = new ObservableCollection<string>(FillComboBox())
                }
            });
        items.Add(new User()
            {
            Name = "Jane Doe",
            Age = 39,
            Mail = "jane@doe-family.com",
            Custom1 = new MyObject
                {
                ControlType = ControlType.ComboBox,
                BoolProp = false,
                ComboProp = "Item 1",
                NormalProp = 1.2,
                ComboMethod = new ObservableCollection<string>(FillComboBox())
                },
            Custom2 = new MyObject
                {
                ControlType = ControlType.Boolean,
                BoolProp = true,
                ComboProp = "Item 2",
                NormalProp = 2.2,
                ComboMethod = new ObservableCollection<string>(FillComboBox())
                }
            });

        lvUsers.ItemsSource = items;

        }

    private IEnumerable<string> FillComboBox ()
        {
        yield return "Item 1";
        yield return "Item 2";
        yield return "Item 3";
        }

    public class User
        {
        public string Name
            {
            get; set;
            }

        public int Age
            {
            get; set;
            }

        public string Mail
            {
            get; set;
            }

        public MyObject Custom1
            {
            get; set;
            }

        public MyObject Custom2
            {
            get; set;
            }

        public override string ToString ()
            {
            return this.Name + ", " + this.Age + " years old";
            }
        }

    public class UserSingleScenario
        {
        public string Name
            {
            get; set;
            }

        public int Age
            {
            get; set;
            }

        public string Mail
            {
            get; set;
            }

        public ControlType ControlType
            {
            get; set;
            }

        public bool BoolProp
            {
            get; set;
            }

        public string ComboProp
            {
            get; set;
            }

        public double NormalProp
            {
            get; set;
            }

        public ObservableCollection<string> ComboMethod
            {
            get; set;
            }

        public override string ToString ()
            {
            return this.Name + ", " + this.Age + " years old";
            }
        }
    }

public class MyObject
    {
    public ControlType ControlType
        {
        get;
        set;
        }

    public bool BoolProp
        {
        get; set;
        }

    public string ComboProp
        {
        get;
        set;
        }
    public double NormalProp
        {
        get;
        set;
        }
    public ObservableCollection<string> ComboMethod
        {
        get;
        set;
        }

    public override string ToString ()
        {
        return ComboProp;
        }
    }
```

Here is the enum in a different directory,

```
public enum ControlType
    {
    Boolean,
    ComboBox,
    TextBlock
    }
```

The actual scnerio is, I have approx 25 columns to add in a gridview. I have one property of checkbox to add with all the column names and one combobox type to add with all the column names as well. and have several double type data which will be rows for the same columns. I am not sure, how to represent this data simply in a window, so that everyone can understand easily.

I had another approach other than the first one. Please have a look at the image...

[Another approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn8d7.png)

The solution to the above-mentioned scenario or any other suggestion is highly appreciated.
Thank you very much for your help and answer...

Comment: Are you sure you want this? Usually a row represents a data object or data record. Each item in the collection generates a row. This way you would get a column of combo boxes, a column of check boxes etc because each item has it's data presented this way. The way you structured your data object, you consolidated related data into an object.

Comment: To get the result you want you would have to structure your data differently and hold on to a strict order of the items: each item must only contain all check box data, the next item all combo box data, etc. When you think about it you will realize that this structure is quite unnatural and more difficult to implement. The table also looks quite odd.

Comment: Thank you for having a look at my issue...
My comment became quite long, so I edited it in the question itself. Please have a look at the bottom of my question.

Any solution of my question or new ideas is much appreciated. Thank you very much...

Comment: As I have said before, the common standard for data presentation is to display each data record in a row. If you can split up the data for grouping, depends on the context and what information you want to express and how the data is related. It can confuse the reader. I can't help you with that. I don't know your data and I don't know the purpose. Randomly splitting up the data record can eliminate any meaning, especially when you remove the relation. Data of a record is always related. But generally, each data item (or user) will map to a row, where each column maps to a property on that item

Comment: At first, I want to thank you for your suggestion. I totally agree with you, but I didn't find any easy UI design other than this by compacting into the GridView. I will try to rethink the UI with my data and will try to find some easy UI solutions... Thanks very much again for your time and for looking into it...

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I want to add Cascading ComboBoxes for Country, State & City in DataGrid WPF MVVM. I find multiple source codes and the developed a sample. You can get it from here  https://github.com/omeraziz/MultipleControlsInDataGridColumnMVVM
[image]